# Why V+1 in Embedding layer(`Embedding(V+1,D)(i)`) where V the vocabulary size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, word-embedding

Suppose

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
...
V = len(tokenizer.word_index)
```

where `V` was the vocabulary size.

I was told that the embedding layer

```
x = Embedding(V+1,D)(i)
```

where `D` the dimension of the output vector. But I wasn't sure why the size of the Embedding layer had to be `(V+1,D)` instead of `(V,D)`, especially because the index of the `tokenizer.word_index` starts at `1` instead of `0`, i.e.

```
tokenizer.word_index
{'UNK': 1,
 'the': 2,
 ',': 3,
 '.': 4,
 'of': 5,
 'and': 6, 
...}
```

so the maximum index(if converted to a list) of `tokenizer.word_index`(a dictionary) was actually `V-1`.

Why `V+1` in Embedding layer(`Embedding(V+1,D)(i)`) where `V` the vocabulary size?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding example.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason is that vocabulary size has to be one unit higher than len(word_index) to be able to index up to the greatest token ID. Read more detail on the following link (there is at least one reason more):
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93651/reason-for-adding-1-to-word-index-for-sequence-modeling